# c# program to remove duplicate elements from a given integer using linq?

Tags: c#

It should be using linq only.for example if an integer 123444 is taken,then it should print as 1234.
I am unable to do it for a single integer.I can do it for a list of integers.

Comment: can i know it in a better way??

Comment: Can it be done with linq alone - possibly, but it would be quite horrendous and not worth the time for a purely theoretical application.   Can it be done *practically* better (and more succinctly) than the answer from @Adil - unlikely.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it by converting the int to string and getting all digits in array. Applying Distinct will remove the duplicates from the array. Once you have array of unique digit you can make string from it using join. Parsing this string as a int will give you number with duplicate digits in it.

```
int j = int.Parse(string.Join("",i.ToString().ToArray().Distinct()));
```